# Easiest Way to Change All Array's Keys?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I'm looking for way to change all array's keys to one key for all elements.

```
array(4) (
  "a" => string(4) "foo1"
  "b" => string(4) "foo2"
  "c" => string(4) "foo3"
  "d" => string(4) "foo4"
)
```

...to:

```
array(4) (
  "a" => string(4) "foo1"
  "a" => string(4) "foo2"
  "a" => string(4) "foo3"
  "a" => string(4) "foo4"
)
```

I would prefer code without any loops.

Comment: You can't have two identical keys in the same array. How would you tell them apart?

Comment: +1, you just want the opposite behavior of an array, whose elements are identified by a unique key.

Comment: I totally failed. Didn't think about that.

Comment: LOL. No, it was more like... I read docs of Mustache and there was "name" as key of array (for all elements). I slept bad. I didn't thought that it must be unique for all elements. So here I am... =D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array(4) (
  "a" => string(4) "foo1"
  "a" => string(4) "foo2"
  "a" => string(4) "foo3"
  "a" => string(4) "foo4"
)
```

This is not possible in PHP. Array can not have more than one key with the same name.

But you can do as

`$array2['a'] = array_values($array);`

Answer (score 1):

As said by Pekka in comment:

> You can't have two identical keys in
>   the same array. How would you tell
>   them apart?

Comment: @Tatu Sorry... It only occured to me later that I could provide an other way to do it. Gaurav's answer is much better, it has my vote!